# What is the difference between 'AAPL' and ['AAPL'] in python pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas

```
by_year.apply(regress,'AAPL',['SPX'])
import statsmodels.api as sm
def regress(data,yvar,xvars):
Y=data[yvar]
X=data[xvars]
X['intercept']=1
result=sm.OLS(Y,X).fit()
return result.params
```

by_year is pandas groupby object, i don't know the difference between 'AAPL' and ['SPX'] why use [] for SPX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, `data['SPX']` returns a `Series` while `data[['SPX']]` returns a `DataFrame`.

Particular to your case, the usage of `['SPX']` makes more sense because your `regress` function tries to add a column named `intercept` to the `X` variable. To make sure that you can actually add that column to the variable `X`, the variable `X` needs to be a `DataFrame`, not a `Series`.

Bottom line is there is a difference in this particular case.

I hope this helps.